# Copying data between databases using Haskell Persistent

Tags: haskell, conduit, haskell-persistent

First up, I have a large Sqlite database. I want to copy a subset of the data in this database to another Sqlite database in a streaming fashion using the Haskell persistent library.

Here's the only I managed to do it, but its very slow (and uses more memory) compared to loading the data in memory and then writing it to the new database.

```
import Database.Persist.Sqlite (SqliteConf(..), runSqlite, runMigration, runSqlPersistMPool)
import Database.Persist (entityVal, Entity, createPoolConfig)
import Data.Pool (Pool)
import Data.Conduit (ConduitT, (.|), runConduit)
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as CL

main :: RIO App ()
main = do
  ipool <- liftIO $ createPoolConfig (SqliteConf "mydb.db" 1)
  opool <- liftIO $ createPoolConfig (SqliteConf "mydbsmall.db" 1)

  liftIO $ flip runSqlPersistMPool opool $ do
    runMigration migrateAll

  liftIO $ flip runSqlPersistMPool ipool $ do
    runConduit $ selectSource (distinct $ from $ \pays -> return pays) .| (migrate opool)

migrate :: (Monad m, MonadIO m)
        => Pool SqlBackend
        -> ConduitT (Entity Pays) Void m ()
migrate pool = CL.mapM_ (\e -> liftIO $ flip runSqlPersistMPool pool $ insertKey (entityKey e) (entityVal e))
```

The problem is in the `migrate` function since I'm calling `runSqlPersistMPool` on every single data in my conduit stream.

What is the right way to do it ?